# Adobe Flex, getting large box with "False" displayed on IE at bottom of app, runs fine on all other browsers

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I've got a strange problem, on IE my Flex app. displays it's normal initial UI fine but there's a big white box at the bottom of the screen with "false" in it.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?  I'm using the latest FlashPlayer 11.3.300.257 no debug.

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, the server had no MIME type setup for CSS and IE9 was balking at trying to load history.css.  Beware.